# Atualizar APP no Google Play Console

Tags: android, app

Boa tarde. Estou com um problema para atualizar meu app já lançado.
Atualizei o grandle dele e agora quando tento lançar uma nova atualização ele apresenta a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já verifiquei a chave do app e é a mesma. Já verifiquei o `applicationId` e está correto também.

Comment: Alterou o versionName e versionCode no build.gradle (app)??

Comment: Alterei sim. Quando da o problema de versão ele orienta alterar essa parte. Dessa vez o erro é que o app nao é compatível com atualização para os usuários =/

Comment: Você fez alguma alteração de versão minima e max do Sdk? Se não, tenta alterar o versionName e versionCode, para valores mais superiores. Exemplo. versionCode de 2 para 10

Comment: Já tentei alterar a versao e nao deu certo. Eu fiz sim uma alteração no min e max do sdk.

Comment: Infelizmente não tenho um resposta para quando isso aconteça, ele tá dando esse erro por alteração no min e max do sdk, talvez isso pode esclarer um pouco a sua dúvida [Multiple APK support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks)